# Does bluemix globalization pipeline support corpus yet?

Tags: ibm-cloud, globalization-pipeline

Does globalization pipeline support corpus yet?
if yes, how to import existing translated properties?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mike. Welcome to Stack Overflow! I added the ibm-bluemix tag so that it is seen. Please be aware that Stack Overflow is for technical questions such as questions with error messages or code. I didn't down vote your question, but that is likely the reason for the down vote. For "How to"-type questions, consider asking them on developerWorks (dW) Answers: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported in the beta version, but we will be outlining new capabilities as they become available in the IBM Globalization Pipeline documentation. Thanks for your question and your feedback.